# Prove $f(x)$ is identically zero.

Tags: calculus, analysis

Consider two functions $f:\mathbb{R}_{\geq0} \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ and $m:(\mathbb{R}_{\geq0})^3\to \mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ with the following properties:

1. $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f(x)=0$
2. For any given $\varepsilon>0 $, a $\delta_\varepsilon>0$ exists s.t. $m(\cdot,\delta_\varepsilon,\cdot)<\varepsilon$. ($\lim\limits_{x\to 0}m(\cdot,x,\cdot)=0$ in uniform limit)
3. $f(x)\leq \int^x_0 m(z,f(z),x)\; dz$
4. $f$ is increasing
5. $m$ is continuous, increasing in the first and second argument, and decreasing in the third argument.
6. Given $x>y>0$, then a $c_{x,y}\in \mathbb{R}$ exists s.t. $m(y,z,x)\leq c_{x,y}\cdot z$

Conjecture: If $(f,m)$ satisfy these conditions then $f(\cdot)\equiv 0$.

Can this be proved with as is or with additional assumptions or can a counterexample be shown?

Progress so far: It's quite simple to show from properties (1), (2) and (3) that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f(x)/x=0$ (i.e. $f'(0)=0$). This can be seen using an epsilon-delta proof by taking the upper bound in (3) and using the desired $\varepsilon$ from (2) to create an upper bound. The integration of the upper bound will then be $x\varepsilon$, dividing by $x$, then gives $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Maybe you are right. You have $f(x)\le\int_0^xm(z,f(z),x)\,dz\,\le\,\int_0^xm(x,f(z),x)\,dz\,\le\,c_{xx}\int_0^xf(z)\,dz$. Let $c(x) = c_{xx}$ and assume that $c(x)>0$ for all $x$ and $h(x) = f(x)/c(x)$ is continuous. Then $h(x)\le\int_0^xc(z)h(z)\,dz$, which, by Gronwall's lemma, leads to $h=0$ and thus $f=0$. However, we don't know whether $c$ or $f$ is continuous...

Comment: I thought about this kind of proof, the problem is that property (6) requires a strict inequality. I even know that $m_2(\cdot, 0,\cdot)=\infty$, so I cannot use a constant $c_{x,x}$. I also cannot know that $f$ is constant outside of 0.

Comment: What is $m_2$ ?

Comment: The derivative with respect to the second argument.

Comment: Where does this problem come from? Just curious.

Comment: If $c_{x,z}$ is integrable over $[0,x]$ for $z$, then you can say something for small $x$ at least. If, e.g., $c_{x,z}\le|x-z|^{-1/2}$, then one can show that $f(x) = 0$ for $x\le 1/4$.

Comment: It comes from a cost-benefit analysis problem. Given a set price (x), i want to show that there is no incentive to deviate from a conjectured advertising strategy. Function $f(\cdot)$ is the cost of deviation, the integral is an upper bound on the benefit of deviation.

I can go into more detail, but it gets more complicated.